# URL full story not linking correctly need htaccess help?

Tags: facebook, .htaccess

I am linking some stories on FaceBook, but the url I have is:

```
http://webpage.com/single.php?2011/02/04/my-story-here.html
```

FaceBook linking doesn't like the ".php?"

Can I do something with my .htaccess page to make it like:

```
http://webpage.com/single.php/2011/02/04/my-story-here.html
```

???

Thanks in advance.

By the way, when you click the link in facebook it goes to this link:

```
http://webpage.com/single.php?2011%2F02%2F04%2Fmy-story-here.html
```

and doesn't show my full story :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) activated in Apache, you can indeed do

```
http://webpage.com/single.php/2011/02/04/my-story-here.html
```

and fetch the part after the `.php` from the `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` variable.